# Change the default upload file location for a particular content type

Tags: 7

I have a content type "Test" which have "upload file" field. Only for this "Test" content type i want to change the location where uploaded file is stored. I want to store anywhere in my drupal instance not just only in sites/all/default/files/subdirectory.

How can I achieve this.

Comment: You should not store files outside of the files directory, as that can be a major security hole. If you need to implement a different save location, you can implement a new file stream, or use mohit_rock's solution below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find some information about how to code changing file names in the [File Path module](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths).

File (Field) Paths allows you to automatically sort and rename your uploaded files using token based replacement patterns to maintain a nice clean filesystem.

[image]

Comment: Added this module. when uploading file getting error "An Ajax Http request terminated abnormally". Error message: PDOException: column not found 1054

Comment: I am also using this module, but i didn't had any issue. probably you can uninstall and install it again

Answer (score 0):

**MaxRequestLen** sometimes gets lowered as a result of server/module updates. Also, adding modules that add to the request length can also introduce this problem. This is why disabling modules can sometimes "fix" the problem.

See http://drupal.org/node/1015938#comment-7412202 for a solution that involves updating your vhost file, eg:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  # 50MB
  MaxRequestLen 52430000
</IfModule>
```

Or try switching from **FastCGI** to **mod_php** or **php-fpm** (if you're using FastCGI).

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question?

Comment: It would be a response to the AJAX error mentioned in Mohini's comment but for the "column not found" part I didn't notice the first time. So, you're right. But as people come accross this page when Googling "An Ajax Http request terminated abnormally", I'd leave it. I came accross this page when researching that error so it would likely save someone else time.